# Show text on TextField after button is pressed (JavaFX)

Tags: button, javafx, calculator

I'm trying to build a calculator, and I have looked all over internet and the examples don't help me, so I have buttons created and everything, I'm trying to display on:

```
    TextField Result = new TextField();
    Result.setEditable(false);
    Result.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
    Result.setMinSize(210, 30);
    Result.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("%.0f" , value));    
    pane.getChildren().add(Result);
```

the number of the button pressed, how do I do that? Let's say the button was:

```
Button uno = new Button("1");
```

uno.setMinSize(40, 40);
pane.getChildren().add(uno);

How do I make the text field Result show number 1?

BIG Thanks!

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/sedj601/CalculatorFx) is a terrible implementation I did for an interview when I first found out about JavaFx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to add a listener for each your button and change your TextField dynamically:

```
uno.pressedProperty().addListener((o, old, newValue) -> Result.setText("1"));
dos.pressedProperty().addListener((o, old, newValue) -> Result.setText("2"));
```

Note, when the user pressed and unpressed a button your listener will react twice with newValue = true/false. Do the additional checking if needed:

```
uno.pressedProperty().addListener((o, old, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue) {
        Result.setText("1")
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**:
Don't forget to remove this line as wrong solution:

```
Result.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("%.0f" , value));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! 

But when I put: 

uno.pressedProperty().addListener((o, old, newValue) -> { if (newValue) { Result.setText("1") } }); 

on the code, it doesn't do anything, it gives me an error.

Comment: Thank you bro! I'm seriusly trying to make this work, I put a deadline for myself and I'm stuck here. This is the error I got:

Comment: I reproduced your problem. You need to remove this line: Result.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("%.0f" , value));.

Comment: I am glad, don't forget to vote and mark the answer as a winner :)

Comment: Oh! I didn't know you can do that here, of course I would gladly do it. Many thanks again!

Comment: It doesn't let me vote up yet, I have a new account :/